# Printing all possible sums of two n-sided dice rolls

Tags: python, combinatorics, dice

For my CS class, we were tasked with writing a program that calculates all the possible results from rolling two *n*-sided dice.  For example, the input of `4` would print `[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8]`.  Or, if the input was `3`, it would print `[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]`.

---

I was given enough test cases that I noticed the pattern that the number range was `[2,n]` and the test cases had a pattern where the pattern was always could be represented by printing the number in `[2,2n+1]` a number in the set `[1,n] U (n,1]` a corresponding number of times.  For example, for `4`, the set would be `[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]` and the output would be `[(one 2), (two 3s), (three 4), (four 5s), (three 6s), (two 7s), and (one 8).`  **This explanation may be horrible, but see the code and you will understand.**

---

The code:

```
def allRolls(sides):
    nums = list(range(1,sides+1)) + reverseIt(list(range(1,sides)))
    index = sides-1
    #the return array
    retVal = []
    #The index to look for in the list of nuts
    cIndex = 0
    for i in range(2,sides*2+1):
        for b in range(nums[cIndex]):
            retVal.append(i)
        cIndex+=1
    retVal.sort()
    return retVal

#Reverses the list
def reverseIt(liste):
    newb =[]
    index = len(liste)-1
    while index>=0:
        newb.append(liste[index])
        index= index-1
    return newb
```

---

The issue:  everyone in my class got it in many fewer lines of code.  What did I do wrong?

---

Code test cases:

Input: `2`

Output:`[2, 3, 3, 4]`

Input: `3`

Output:`[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]`

Input: `4`

Output: `[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8]`

Comment: Was it a requirement to output the numbers in ascending order?

Comment: Yes it was @CarstenS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @BenC mostly put a code dump, I'll explain ways that your code could have improved.

---

## `reverseIt`

Programming this is just *wrong* in Python.
This is as there are *two* ways to do this.

```
>>> list(reversed([1, 2, 3]))
[3, 2, 1]
>>> [1, 2, 3][::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

As an alternate way to this you could just calculate the `range` backwards off the bat.

```
>>> list(range(10, 0, -1))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In short you could halve your code just by removing this.

---

If you wanted to keep it, then you would want to use the reversed range.
And do pretty much what you are now. To get:

```
def reverseIt(indexable):
    lst = []
    for index in range(len(indexable) - 1, -1, -1):
        lst.append(indexable[index])
    return lst
```

You could then use a list comprehension, if amount of lines dictates how good your code is.

```
def reverseIt(indexable):
    return [indexable[index] for index in range(len(indexable) - 1, -1, -1))]
```

---

## `allRolls`

- `nums` is pointless if you use a different algorithm. (Which is also more intuitive.)
- `index` is never used.
- `retVal` can be changed to a comprehension.
- Manually counting `cIndex` is a frowned upon in Python.

In short, use a different algorithm.
The pseudo-code for this could be:

```
fn allRolls(sides):
    list = List()
    for dice1-face in dice-faces:
        for dice2-face in dice-faces:
            add dice1-face + dice2-face to list
    return sorted list
```

Or in Python:

```
fn allRoles(sides):
    ret = []
    for a in range(1, sides + 1):
        for b in range(1, sides + 1):
            ret.append(a + b)
    ret.sort()
    return ret
```

If you take it the next step then you would get @BenC's answer.

---

## Misc

In short, you just used the wrong algorithm.

And in Python you should:

- Use `all_rolls` instead of `allRoles` to follow [function and variable naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).
- Have a space on both sides of operators, `index >= 0` or `newb = []` to increase readability.

Answer (score 12):

For your specific case of two rolls of n-sided dice:

```
def sumsFromTwoRolls(sides):
    return sorted(a + b for a in range(1, sides + 1) for b in range(1, sides + 1))
```

---

As `sides` or `number of rolls` gets big, you would want a more generic solution, and also probably an algorithm that sorts as you go, instead of looping through again afterwards with `sort()`.

Another little trick is that (depending on how much you're supposed to be implementing yourself), `reverseIt(arr)` is just `arr[::-1]` (slicing with a negative step starts from the end).

Answer (score 11):

I've got a suggestion to an alternative way of generating your list based on your own thoughts on how the sequence grows. But first a few general remarks related to the style of your code.

- *Naming of functions and variables in Python are usually `snake_case`* – This indicates that it should be `all_rolls`, `reverse_list`, and so on
- *Avoid abbreviations for variable names* – Use better descriptive names for all variables. Stuff like `cIndex`, `retVal`, `nums` and `newb` doesn't describe much on the use and why you have this variables. Better names could be `secondary_index`, `result`, `dice_numbers` and `reversed_list`...
- *Add more spaces both horizontally and vertically* – Be a little more generous with your spaceing. I.e. Use `range(2, sides * 2 + 1)`, or `cIndex += 1`, or `while index >= 0`. In addition you could add vertical space (or blank lines) within a function before new loops or blocks, and the guidelines dictates two blank lines before functions (and classes)
- *Look into [slices](http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-python) and use of these* –  Slices can solve your problem a lot more elegant, based on your own thinking. The basic examples as some have mentioned already is to use `[::-1]` to reverse an entire list, in one swift go.

### Alternate solutions

If we look at the case for a 4 sided die, we get the following lists, as based on your suggestion:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  3 4 5 6 7    = [ 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8 ]
    4 5 6
      5
```

This pattern can easily be regenerated using slicing. The first iteration of the list is simply `list(range(2, 2*sides + 1)`. The next iteration we skip the first and last element, which can be expressed as the slice `[1:-1]`. And this we can continue doing until there are no more elements left in the temporary list.

In code this look the following:

```
def all_rolls(sides):
    """Return sum of all combinations of two dice with given number of sides."""
    result = []
    temp_list = list(range(2, 2*sides+1))

    while temp_list:
        result.extend(temp_list)
        temp_list = temp_list[1:-1]

    return sorted(result)
```

Note how I also added a simple, but hopefully sufficient docstring to state what the function is meant to do, and have removed some of the unneeded loops and ranges.

Answer (score 8):

On top of @BenC answer which provide an efficient writting for a straitforward algorithm, I'll provide a version where you build the resulting list already sorted, saving you some computation.

The main thing is that @BenC answer can easily be extended to provide more than 2 rolls of the dice, but by further examinating the structure of the desired output we can craft the required list specificaly for 2 rolls:

- Each number between `2` and `2 * num_sides` appears in the output sequence;
- The first number appear 1 time, the second number appear 2 times, …, the nth number appear n time until a number appears `num_sides` times;
- After that, the next number appears one time less than the previous one, with the number `2 * num_sides` appearing once.

Given that, we can iterate through `range(1, num_sides)` to get the number of ascending items, and then through `range(num_sides, 0, -1)` to get the number of descending items. The value of the items starts at 2 and end when we finish iterating.

### First implementation

```
def sum_of_two_rolls(num_sides):
    result = []
    value = 2

    for num_repeat in range(1, num_sides):
        for _ in range(num_repeat):
            result.append(value)
        value += 1

    for num_repeat in range(num_sides, 0, -1):
        for _ in range(num_repeat):
            result.append(value)
        value += 1

    return result
```

Note the use of `_` when we do not care about the variable used to iterate and just want to loop a certain amount of times.

But this solution is not very elegant since it contains two loops that are very similar.

### Second implementation

We now want to merge both `for` loops since they perform the same operation. But we cannot use `+` to concatenate two `range` objects (assuming Python 3, since in Python 2 range returns lists and you can concatenate lists using `+`). However, since `range` objects are iterators, we can make good use of [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) which concatenates any number of iterators:

```
from itertools import chain

def sum_of_two_rolls(num_sides):
    result = []
    value = 2

    for num_repeat in chain(range(1, num_sides), range(num_sides, 0, -1)):
        for _ in range(num_repeat):
            result.append(value)
        value += 1

    return result
```

But we can make this code even more pythonic.

### Third implementation

The first thing to note is that using some sort of counter value being incremented inside a for loop is a common anti-pattern and is best served with `enumerate`. In our case, we need to start at `2` instead of the default `0` usualy used with `enumerate`. Luckily, `enumerate`'s optional second argument let us do that:

```
from itertools import chain

def sum_of_two_rolls(num_sides):
    result = []

    for value, repeats in enumerate(chain(range(1, num_sides), range(num_sides, 0, -1)), 2):
        for _ in range(repeats):
            result.append(value)

     return result
```

### Last improvement: the one-liner

Lastly, creating an empty list and appending to it in a loop is also an anti-pattern since a list-comprehension is most likely possible to use and has better performances.

Since this is the only computation that the function is doing, you can directly return the list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

def sum_of_two_rolls(num_sides):
    return [v for v, r in enumerate(chain(range(1, num_sides), range(num_sides, 0, -1)), 2) for _ in range(r)]
```

Or splitted over several lines for better readability:

```
from itertools import chain

def sum_of_two_rolls(num_sides):
    return [v
            for v, r in enumerate(
                chain(range(1, num_sides), range(num_sides, 0, -1)),
                2)
            for _ in range(r)]
```